# How to Return user to login.html if the session is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to redirect the user with php file if the Session is empty?

for example this code:

pSession.php

```
<?php
   include('pConfig.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select UserName from userinfo where UserName = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['UserName'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("Location: ../login3.html");
      die();
   }
?>
```

and use it in javascript:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkSession();
})
function checkSession() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../srtdash/php/pSession.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
           console.log("Welcome to Credit Investigation");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../srtdash/jsScripts/jsIndex.js"></script>
```

Am I doing it right to redirect if the User Actually logged on ? or if not How can I redirect the user to login.html if he/she is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
<?php
        include('pConfig.php');
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            echo "Welcome to Home page, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
        } else {
            header("Location: ../login3.html");
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) and [mysql_query()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) are all deprecated.